# How to automate StructType creation for passing RDD to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I want to save `RDD` as a parquet file. To do this, I pass RDD to `DataFrame` and then I use a structure to save `DataFrame` as a parquet file:

```
    val aStruct = new StructType(Array(StructField("id",StringType,nullable = true),
                                       StructField("role",StringType,nullable = true)))
    val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered, aStruct)
```

The question is how to create `aStruct` automatically for all columns assuming that all of them are `StringType`? Also, what is the meaning of `nullable = true`? Does it mean that all empty values will be substituted by `Null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the built-in `toDF`?

```
scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("1", "roleA"), ("2", "roleB"), ("3", "roleC")))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[60] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> val colNames = List("id", "role")
colNames: List[String] = List(id, role)

scala> val myDF = myRDD.toDF(colNames: _*)
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, role: string]

scala> myDF.show
+---+-----+
| id| role|
+---+-----+
|  1|roleA|
|  2|roleB|
|  3|roleC|
+---+-----+

scala> myDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- role: string (nullable = true)

scala> myDF.write.save("myDF.parquet")
```

The `nullable=true` simply means that the specified column can contain `null` values (this is esp. useful for `int` columns which would normally not have a `null` value -- `Int` has no `NA` or `null`).

Comment: what if the list of features is long? I want to avoid using ("id", "role"). Is it possible to create list of features, assuming that each RDD has the same structure `RDD[Map[String,Any]]`, where String is the feature ?

Comment: If the list of features is long you can either pass no params to `toDF` (which causes spark to use the column names `_1`, `_2`...) or you can use a list `colNames` and unpack it like so: `myRDD.toDF(colNames: _*)`

Comment: It says `Cannot resolve symbol toDF`. He probado con Spark 2.0.0 y 1.6.2: `val myDF = rdd.toDF(colNames: _*)`, where `rdd` is `RDD[Map[String,Any]]`. Don't understand why it happens.

Comment: You will need to import implicits: `import sqlContext.implicits._`

Comment: Ok, if I do so, it does not recognize `sqlContext`. In my POM file I have this dependency, where spark.version is 2.0.0 `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Something may be wrong with your installation which would be beyond the scope of this question. If you do not have a `sqlContext`available you may need to create one: `SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)`

Comment: When I do this `val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._`, it says that SQLContext is deprecated... and then it cannot find the method `toDF` I am using Spark 2.0.0. In general is it a good idea to use 2.0.0 or is it unstable at this moment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128190/discussion-between-evan058-and-duckertito).

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615662/todf-does-not-compile-though-import-sqlcontext-implicits-is-used